# android out of memory and fatal signal 11 error

Tags: android, memory, signals

I have a total of 24 bitmaps in my android game, and there is a total of 644kb.

My game has 3 activities, the main menu activity, the level menu activity , and the game activity.

I enter the first one, then the second one, i choose my level and start the game. After I finish the level, a window pops up to select what i want to do (retry, back to menu, next level) and i choose next level, I play the next level, finish it, and then i choose again to go on the next level, but the game stops.

```
 01-19 17:03:54.100: E/dalvikvm-heap(8604): Out of memory on a 16000016-byte allocation.
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ece568 self=0x40e2bb00
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   | sysTid=8604 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075340848
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   | schedstat=( 4853149437 2903961165 6778 ) utm=426 stm=59 core=0
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)


    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:376)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:406)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at com.example.happylines.GameActivity$Screen.LoadBitmaps(GameActivity.java:357)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at com.example.happylines.GameActivity$Screen.<init>(GameActivity.java:474)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at com.example.happylines.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:300)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2043)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4782)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    01-19 17:03:54.110: I/dalvikvm(8604):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-19 17:03:54.120: A/libc(8604): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0004d190 (code=1), thread 8604 (mple.happylines)
```

I don't understand why can my phone go out of memory, because if I add all the bitmaps sizes i only have 644kb... And also, whenever I switch an activity I use finish(); after start activity.

Here I load my bitmaps in the game activity.

```
face_happy = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.happy_face);
            face_happy = Game.ScaleWidth(face_happy, Game.faceRadio);
            face_sad = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.sad_face);
            face_sad = Game.ScaleWidth2(face_sad, Game.faceRadio);
            particlez[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.red_particle);
            particlez[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.blue_particle);
            particlez[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.green_particle);
            particlez[3] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.yellow_particle);
            particlez[0] = Game.ScaleWidth(particlez[0], 14);
            particlez[1] = Game.ScaleWidth(particlez[1], 14);
            particlez[2] = Game.ScaleWidth(particlez[2], 14);
            particlez[3] = Game.ScaleWidth(particlez[3], 14);
            particlez[4] = Game.ScaleWidth(particlez[0], 10);
            particlez[5] = Game.ScaleWidth(particlez[1], 10);
            particlez[6] = Game.ScaleWidth(particlez[2], 10);
            particlez[7] = Game.ScaleWidth(particlez[3], 10);

            finish_bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.finishscreen);
            play = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.play_button);
            menu = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.menu_button);
            retry = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.retry_button);

            play = Game.ScaleWidth(play, 5.4f);
            retry = Game.ScaleWidth(retry, 5.4f);
            menu = Game.ScaleWidth(menu, 5.4f);

            playY = Game.height - 2 * play.getHeight();
            menuY = playY;
            retryY = playY;
            menuX = Game.width / 2 - menu.getWidth() / 2;
            playX = menuX + 1.5f * play.getWidth();
            retryX = menuX - 1.5f * play.getWidth();
```

And here i go to the game activity again when i press the next level button.

```
Game.level++;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,
                            GameActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your images might be 644 KB on disk, but are uncompressed in memory to display them, which is why Android is trying to allocate 16 MB for a single image, giving you an out of memory exception.

To avoid this, you'll want to use images that are sized correctly for the device that is running, which you can do by taking advantage of resource qualifiers for your drawable folders:

```
Images for mdpi devices: /res/drawable-mdpi
Images for hdpi devices: /res/drawable-hdpi
Images for xhdpi devices: /res/drawable-xhdpi
Images for xxhdpi devices: /res/drawable-xxhdpi
```

When you request an image (say, R.drawable.myImage), it will look for a myImage file in the folder that has the density qualifier that best matches the device. This lets you automatically make sure that small density devices are using images with a smaller memory footprint.

More information here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Android have some problems with releasing bitmaps memory, so I think will better to add additional cache for loaded bitmaps and not load it again in the next level. You can create with cache as Singletone and stores instances of loaded bitmaps into it. It should helps with crashes and decrease time for start level.

Answer (score 0):

One of the fastest way to resolve your problem is to use the Picasso library from Jake Wharton. It enables in one line of code to load images and manage caching, transformations, download etc..

Here is the link to download the library: http://square.github.io/picasso/

All the code you need is :

```
Picasso.with(context).load(image_ressource).into(yourImageView);
```

:)

Comment: I'm not using imageviews.

Comment: ok, so I suggest to you to decode your drawables with this method :

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html